difference between l2 penalty and l2 loss in SAE
I was reading this paper from Anthropic https://transformer-circuits.pub/2024/scaling-monosemanticity/index.html and in the paper loss is defined like this :$$
L = \mathbb{E}_x \left[ \| x - \hat{x} \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_i f_i(x) \cdot \| W_{:,i}^{\text{dec}} \|_2 \right]
 $$ and it was stated like: The loss function
L is the combination of an L2 penalty on the reconstruction loss and an L1 penalty on feature activations. but isn't it L2 penalty here L2 loss instead of L2 penalty since there is no L2 regularization here. I would define reconstruction loss as L2 loss instead of penalty. Can you clarify it? Thanks

Could you define the terms in that expression?
